# How to use two different size canvas in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-canvas

I am creating two different Canvas, `pcanvas1` and `pcanvas2`. Canvas sizes are different.

```
bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100 , Config.ARGB_8888);
pcanvas1 = new Canvas();
pcanvas1.setBitmap(bitmap); 
bitmap1 =  Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200 , Config.ARGB_8888);
pcanvas2 = new Canvas();
pcanvas2.setBitmap(bitmap1);
```

I am using same bitmap in both Canvas but sizes are different.

I need to draw circle at the same point on both bitmaps.

How to achieve this ? In case if Canvas sizes are different.

Comment: Do you have a feed-back on the solution?

Comment: Sorry so for I did not try, I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Scale:

```
scale_x = bitmap2.width/bitmap1.width;
scale_y = bitmap2.height/bitmap1.height;

canvas1.drawLine(startX1, startY1, stopX1, stopY1, paint);

canvas2.drawLine(startX1*scale_x, startY*scale_y, stopX*scale_x, stopY*scale_y, paint);
```

something like the above.